# Is it possible to verify a Stack Overflow user's account?

Tags: discussion, users

I want a user of my website to get certain privileges based on his Stack Overflow rating. Obviously, I need to verify the Stack Overflow user is who he says it is - or I would have probably a hundred "Jon Skeet's" i.e. users who claim to be Jon.

CLARIFICATION:
Yes, adding something to the profile is a sure fire way of doing things, but I am confused why its the primary suggestion and it seems to me that it is a high friction, 2-step process that involves considerably more work for the user. What are the specific diadvantages and risks of using the "Stackoverflow application approach"?

Comment: There's a way where you can make people sign in with their stack exchange account and authorize you to view information about them, e.g. their account name. I don't know exactly how it works though.

Comment: Register an Stack Apps application and let the users sign in with their SE account. See https://stackapps.com/search?q=register and https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

Comment: The API way is boring.  Instead, make the user temporarily add a random, unique, and mildly embarrassing string to their user profile. When you verify it's there, you know they control that account.

Comment: On what scale do you wish to implement this? Are you expecting 10 users to link SO/SE accounts? 100? 100k? If you're expecting a sizable number, it'll be annoying and inefficient to use the profile-modification thing, even if it's all automated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't tap into Stack Exchange itself and probably prefer to not build a whole app for that, most simple way is what was mentioned in a comment: ask the user to add something to their About Me section of the user profile, or put an avatar you give them, until verified.